# Get incorrect height of NSTextView by using boundingRectWithSize: options: attributes: context: method

Tags: macos, font-size, nstextview

When I use "boundingRectWithSize: options: attributes:  context: method" to get size of NSTextView's content it has a big unnecessary gap on bottom (font is AvenirNext-Regular), also it returns smaller incorrect size when switch to another font (such as system font).

[System font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSpKO.png)

[AvenirNext-Regular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtiSO.png)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I get suitable size that does not contain that blank section, just let text fit the size? thks.

Comment: Have you tried this NS(Attributed)String+Geometrics category: https://github.com/jerrykrinock/CategoriesObjC/tree/master/NS(Attributed)String%2BGeometrics